# How do I save multiple user created checkboxes? c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

When I currently save, it saves the checkboxes (but only the color and it's contents, but not if it was checked for some reason), but of course, since I only have 1 setting for each of the properties of the check box (like color, if it is checked(which doesn't work), and it's content), the last checkbox to be added by the user overwrites every other checkbox.
The other problem is that it only creates 1 checkbox, and I don't know how to create the exact number of checkboxes the user has created, with code.
Yesterday I almost spent the whole day looking for solutions, and today I have only spent some hours, maybe two.
Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBoxes is a bool value, to tell it if it's checked or unchecked. Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBoxText
I started to code in c# some days ago, so my code is probably sloppy.  Here is my code:

```
        private void DoneBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        playSimpleSound();
        TextRange descText = new TextRange(descTextBox.Document.ContentStart, descTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
        CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
        c.Name = "CheckBoxs";
        c.IsChecked = false;
        c.Content = TitleTextBox.Text + "\n" + descText.Text;
        c.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SkyBlue);

        checkBoxPanel.Children.Add(c);
        checkBoxScroll.Content = checkBoxPanel;
        CreateTaskPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBoxText = (string)c.Content;
        


    }


    private void MainWindow1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.Value == true)
        {
            CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
            c.IsChecked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBoxes;
            c.Content = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBoxText;
            c.Foreground = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBoxColor;
            checkBoxPanel.Children.Add(c);
        }
        Properties.Settings.Default.Value = true;
    }
    private void MainWindow1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {

        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

    }
```

Comment: What is this for `Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBoxes` and the line below that?

Comment: @Charlieface , true I should've probably explained that. Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBoxes is a bool value, to tell it if it's checked or unchecked.
Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBoxText, is to tell what the contents of the checkbox is.
I also added a new thing when it closes, you can read it on the original post.

Comment: Are your checkboxes visible at the moment they are retrieving the value of Checked from the settings?